# Capistrano Ruby: Refactoring Reused String Values

Tags: ruby, capistrano, capistrano3

I have a couple tasks within my **deploy.rb** file that execute within my theme folder.

I currently define them as follows:

```
namespace :deploy do
   desc 'NPM Build Production'
   task :npm_build_production do
      on roles(:app) do
          within "#{release_path}/web/app/themes/example" do
             execute :npm, "install --silent --no-progress"
             execute :npm, "run build:production"
          end;
      end
   end
end

before 'deploy:updated', 'deploy:npm_build_production'
```

Everything is working correctly with this implementation, but since there are multiple instances where I use this path, I'd like to extract it to a symbol or variable. I am new to Ruby and am running into some issues.

I have tried using the code below, but for some reason the path ends up being wrong when executed in my tasks.

```
set :theme_path, -> { "#{release_path}/web/app/themes/example" }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These variables are set on different stages of implementation. for example the `release_path` variable is not defined in the setting variables section. Move your variable to your execution block for tasking and it will work . for example this snipped will work

`namespace :deploy do
   desc 'NPM Build Production'
   task :npm_build_production do
      on roles(:app) do
          theme_path = "#{release_path}/web/app/themes/example"
          within theme_path do
             execute :npm, "install --silent --no-progress"
             execute :npm, "run build:production"
          end;
      end
   end
end`

also you will be able to fetch some variables using this way while setting other variables like `fetch(:varible_name)` but I am not sure it is feasible for the release_path since it is a scoped variable

here is how you could do it with a function

```
      def theme_path(release_path)
          "#{release_path}/web/app/themes/example" 
      end
```

just call this function with your release_path variable and you will have the themepath wherever you want. inside your deployment logic.

Comment: Wouldn't he need to set the `theme_path`varibale like this: `set(:theme_path,  "#{release_path}/web/app/themes/example")` in order to use in other code blocks by calling `fetch`?

Comment: as I indicated the release_path is a scoped variable which is not available to be accessed everywhere

Comment: Ok, so How does this solves his problem in order to reuse the `theme_path` variable?

Comment: he cannot reuse it. he can generate a global variable for this or a simple function that gets the release_path and returns the theme_path

Comment: What would the simple function or global variable options look like? What about if I separated the theme_path variable to just be the path extension and concatenated the two in the task?

Comment: That's a feasible option. you can simply define your function like this
`def theme_path(release_path)`
  `"#{release_path}/web/app/themes/example"`
`end`

Comment: Thanks that seems to work well enough for my purposes! If you can update your answer to show the path addition string "web/app", etc. outside of the task, via function or otherwise, I will accept the answer.